# How does a tree with such an extreme curvature form?

Tags: trees, pennsylvania

Back in my hometown in Northeast Pennsylvania, I remembered that there was this tree down my road that had an **extreme** curvature to it.  Now, I could see a branch of a tree growing like this, but this trees curved part was its trunk and very low to the ground, and then it started to grow straight up.  Here is that tree:

[image: Crazy tree]

Now in my [previous question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/16860/what-causes-a-tree-to-split-into-multiple-trunks), I asked how a tree split off into multiple trunks, but this is something far more bizarre.  How and why did this tree grow like this?  It's almost hard to believe that a tree grew this way.

Comment: Is that a [trail tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trail_trees)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That tree got bent over but not snapped when it was just tall enough so that its tip was where the end of the bend is now.  One of the small branches near that tip happened to point upwards after the bending.  That branch basically became the new trunk.  The existing bent wood stayed where it was, with layers added each year enlarging its diameter.  Now 25 year later you come along and see it.

The tree survived its early trauma, but if it weren't growing at the side of a field that is actively maintained, it probably would not have gotten enough light to compete.  Note that some of its branches are already dead.

Answer (score 0):

Trees such as this in the jungle. Bent in a certain way. By natives tell you something. So the tree was bent. Normally to point in a way to lead you. Such as to a spring, trail, village, or other. Bent as that it could not native to that area be cave or shelter with rock under it this way. If it was bent for a reason. It looks like the tree top was buried with the second limb left to grow. Some from of land mark. I see water near it. So did some one want you to know there was shelter near a stream if using it for a trail??

Comment: There is a stream nearby this tree.  I'm sure many years ago there was Native Americans living in the area so it's possible.

Comment: Bushcrafters who have years to work with and a commitment or necessity to use only natural materials will do this on purpose to prep for the project decades hence when they'll need a piece of wood just that shape. Probably not the long arch, but maybe the joint where the growth changes direction.

Comment: I agree. Boat makers will bend trees for the bow & tail of our outriggers for the center board if built the old way. But not into a full arch.